# I keep getting Invalid Classname: Ambiguous match found error when setting up Google Play Games in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm using Unity 2018.3.8f1 and Play Services Plugin 0.964.
However I cant seem to use `Window > Google Play Games > Setup` because I get the following error:

[image]

I've tried deleting and reinstalling the plugin and I've tried using `Player services Resolver > Force Resolve`. Nothing seems to work.

There is no information about this error when searched in Google.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem there. I fixed it by replacing firebase 6.6.0 to 5.5.0
https://dl.google.com/firebase/sdk/unity/firebase_unity_sdk_5.5.0.zip